MinGW/MSys 2 doesn't seem to recognize TZ environment variable
I work on a legacy system originally written in C for 3b2 SVR3, later in C++ for Sun/Solaris, now mainly for Linux.  We have a few users who require our apps to run on Windows Servers, so we have accommodated that for the last 18 years using MSys / MinGW, cross compiled from our *nix-based development machines.  We're now trying to upgrade to MSys 2 and have run into what appears to be an intractable problem that no amount of searching has turned up an answer to.
Our application works across multiple time zones simultaneously. We can't rely on a static system time zone setting to operate properly. We get our time zone definitions from the IANA database, installed as zoneinfo files in the traditional locations, depending upon environment. We update zoneinfo for our users as the need arises.
For as long as I can remember (I've worked on this for nearly 30 years), it was adequate to
putenv("TZ=<your-timezone-here>");
tzset();

to get methods like mktime() and localtime() to produce the information we needed.  That has stopped working now that we've moved to MSys 2.
Additionally, most of our code doesn't care what the initial time zone is, but one method insists that the TZ variable have some value (any value, it doesn't care). It really doesn't matter why TZ must be set - that code exposes another symptom that we might not otherwise have noticed so quickly: upon entry to any of our programs, the TZ environment variable has been removed from the environment.
The final curiosity is that MSys 2 comes with a date program that seems to work just fine with the TZ environment variable, as do printenv and ls, seeming to indicate that what we need to do can be done.
We have a short test program we've been using to demonstrate the problem and with any luck, prove that we've found a solution:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int
main(int argc, const char *const *argv)
{
    const char *tz = getenv("TZ");
    const char *ptz = tz ? tz : "TZ not set";

    printf("at entry: %s\n", ptz);

    time_t now = time(NULL);

    putenv("TZ=US/Pacific");
    tzset();

    printf("in %s it is now %s", getenv("TZ"), ctime(&now));

    putenv("TZ=US/Eastern");
    tzset();

    printf("in %s it is now %s", getenv("TZ"), ctime(&now));

    return 0;
}

When I run the above on our Linux dev machine, I get the following output:
$ printenv TZ
US/Central
$ date "+%F %T %Z"
2024-08-15 10:20:55 CDT
$ ./msystest
at entry: US/Central
in US/Pacific it is now Thu Aug 15 08:20:55 2024
in US/Eastern it is now Thu Aug 15 11:20:55 2024

Under MSys 2, just seconds later, I get the following:
$ printenv TZ
US/Central
$ date "+%F %T %Z"
2024-08-15 10:20:57 CDT
$ ./msystest
at entry: TZ not set
in US/Pacific it is now Thu Aug 15 16:20:57 2024
in US/Eastern it is now Thu Aug 15 16:20:57 2024

Using ldd on MSys 2, we've noticed that there are different DLLs referenced by date and msystest:
$ ldd /usr/bin/date
        ntdll.dll => /c/Windows/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x7ff962d20000)
        KERNEL32.DLL => /c/Windows/System32/KERNEL32.DLL (0x7ff961b30000)
        KERNELBASE.dll => /c/Windows/System32/KERNELBASE.dll (0x7ff960340000)
        msys-intl-8.dll => /usr/bin/msys-intl-8.dll (0x430b30000)
        msys-2.0.dll => /usr/bin/msys-2.0.dll (0x180040000)
        msys-iconv-2.dll => /usr/bin/msys-iconv-2.dll (0x5603f0000)

$ ldd msystest
        ntdll.dll => /c/Windows/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x7ff962d20000)
        KERNEL32.DLL => /c/Windows/System32/KERNEL32.DLL (0x7ff961b30000)
        KERNELBASE.dll => /c/Windows/System32/KERNELBASE.dll (0x7ff960340000)
        msvcrt.dll => /c/Windows/System32/msvcrt.dll (0x7ff962790000)

So our question is - is our problem the result of the differing DLLs, and if so, how do we get the msys DLLs built into our programs rather than the msvcrt DLL?
We've done a lot of searching online to try to resolve this to little avail. We usually get 1 of 2 answers:

Windows doesn't work that way so you can't do what you want with MSys
This is how you build a DLL with MinGW

Needless to say, the answers are either (1) wrong, or (2) answering the wrong question.  Any help anyone can provide/point us to would be invaluable.

This is a known bug in MSys2. It deliberately removes the TZ environment variable when invoking non-MSys2 applications.
Diving into the source code, this happens in build_env(), which is invoked when an MSys program calls a non-Msys program. Specifically, an MSys program is one that is accessed through a path that goes through a Cygwin mount with the MOUNT_CYGWIN_EXEC flag. On the mount command line, that's the cygexec option.
So I'll list several potential workarounds. Note that I haven't tested any of them, I'm just basing this on reading the code and other material.

If you control both the code of the program that cares about the TZ environment variable and the program that invokes it, pass the desired timezone information in some different variable like TZ_YES_MSYS2_I_MEAN_IT, and run setenv("TZ", getenv("TZ_YES_MSYS2_I_MEAN_IT"), 1); tzset(); (plus error checking) in your program's startup code. Note that if your application has multiple programs, this needs to be done in each program, since invoking another program with exec* functions will remove TZ.
If you control the program that invokes your program, have it set TZ via a non-MSys2 program. For example, call cmd /c "set TZ=… && myprogram". Beware that quoting paths and command-line arguments is tricky with cmd. This is what LLVM ended up doing (they reported the bug I cited above).
If your program is located in c:\path\to\my\program.exe, run mount -o cygexec c:\path\to\my /usr/my/bin and invoke your program through /usr/my/bin/program.exe. This bypasses the TZ removal.


That might resolve the issue of the TZ variable being removed, but that was merely a secondary symptom of the bigger problem.  We can correctly set the TZ variable in our programs with putenv() (as in the included test program) and still get the wrong answer when we ask "what time is it in the local time zone?"

We've resolved the issue, but not the way we wanted to.
The root of the problem is that MSys 2 has 3 64 bit modes of operation, which are not 100% interchangeable.  There's core msys, msvcrt, and ucrt.  The msvcrt and ucrt modes use service DLLs provided with Windows, which as noted in dozens of other posts I ran into while researching the problem, "doesn't do time zones that way", that way being using the zoneinfo database along with the TZ environment variable to interpret times in various time zones.  Thus, this isn't a bug, it's a feature.  Core msys mode uses its own service DLL that uses the zoneinfo database and TZ environment variable the way *nix users are accustomed to.
Our problem was that the cross-compiler available to us only built for msvcrt.  Given a little more time, we would probably have been able to work out the proper specs file and copied the required libraries from an installed MSys 2 machine to make the cross-compiler produce exactly what we wanted (we got really close), but the people in control of the calendar exerted enough pressure to force us into running our automated builds on an MSys 2 machine instead.  It (the build) is slower, but it works.
